# Step in derivation of Lagrangian mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation

There is a step in expressing the momentum in terms of general coordinates that confuses me ([Link](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Variational_Principles_in_Classical_Mechanics_(Cline)/06%3A_Lagrangian_Dynamics/6.03%3A_Lagrange_Equations_from_dAlemberts_Principle))
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{i}^{n} m_{i} \ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{i} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}\right) \delta q_{j}=\sum_{i}^{n}\left\{\frac{d}{d t}\left(m_{i} \dot{\mathbf{r}}_{i} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}\right)-m_{i} \dot{\mathbf{r}}_{i} \cdot \frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}\right)\right\} \delta q_{j}.
\end{equation}

If we write $\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{r}_{i}\cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_{i}}{\partial q_{j}})$, then we have $\frac{d}{d t}\left(m_{i} \dot{\mathbf{r}}_{i} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}\right)+m_{i} \dot{\mathbf{r}}_{i} \cdot \frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}\right)$ and not a minus. So why is there a minus in the derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(m_i \dot{r}_i \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\right)
= m_i\ddot{r}_i \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j} + 
m_i\dot{r}_i\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\right)$$
so
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(m_i\dot{r}_i\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\right)- 
m_ir_i \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\right)= m_i
\ddot{r}_i\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}
$$